# How to check if one element is in same position as another javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a thing that is kind of cool and basically, it's just drawing without the use of a canvas because I thought "What the hell, I'll play around with some JS". Right now my computer can handle around 4,000 different elements before becoming laggy and I can make that number larger if I could tell if there was a div under the new div I am creating, and then remove it.

How can I detect if there is already an element where the script is going to be creating a new element and remove the existing element without the use of external libraries?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Drawing thing</title>
</head>
<body onmousedown="setYes()" onmouseup="setNo()">

    <div id="appendThingsHere"></div>


<style>
.circle{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
    border-radius:50%;
    position:absolute;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
    user-select:none;
}
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
#appendThingsHere{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
</style>
<script>
var mouseDown = "no";
var elements = 0;

function setYes(){
    mouseDown = "yes";
}

function setNo(){
    mouseDown = "no";
}

document.body.onmousemove = function(e){

    if(mouseDown === "yes"){
        if(elements < 4000){

            var newCircle = document.createElement("div");
            newCircle.className = "circle";
            newCircle.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px';
            newCircle.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px';

            try{
                var elem = document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX - 25 + 'px', e.clientY - 25 + 'px');
                elem.parentElement.removeChild(elem);
                elements = elements - 1;
                alert("Got one!");
            }
            catch(err){

            }

            elements ++;

            document.getElementById('appendThingsHere').appendChild(newCircle);

        }
    }

}



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/hocowa/edit?html,output

Comment: You aren't actually using a canvas, you're just appending elements to the DOM. With a canvas, there would be no limit to how many circles you can draw.

Comment: I know that, that's what I said. But with 4k elements in the DOM, it gets kind of laggy. Thats my problem...

Comment: Yeah but what he was saying was that you SHOULD absolutely be using canvas for this.

Comment: You could run throught the list of every element to check whether it has the same position as the new element you're about to draw, but this will slow you down even more, and is not perfect: an area may be completely coloured by neighbouring elements, even if no single element has exactly the same position. The other option is to look at every pixel you're about to colour, and if all are already coloured, don't draw the new element; however, I'm not aware of a way to find the colour of a pixel in a page unless it's part of a canvas or an image.

Comment: Maybe we're looking at this wrong - perhaps only create a circle if there isn't one under it? Maybe that would be easier...

Comment: I think the elemenentFromPoint() answer is probably the best suggestion so far, but again, checking whether another element is in *exactly* the same spot isn't a perfect solution.

Comment: Not perfect, but good. If I could just get it to work...

Comment: You should indeed check what is already there, and then decide whether to draw a new circle or not. The best method I can think of: check a number of points along the edge of your new circle (preferable as many as there are pixels along the circumference of the circle, but too many will slow you down), then if you catch an older circle, check how close its center is to the new circle, then draw your new circle if you don't find anything close enough to the new position.

Comment: You may want to try with squares first, then you'd only have to check under the 4 corner pixels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `document.elementFromPoint(x, y);`

Don't think you'd be able to handle multiple elements in a single point though.  May have to iterate whilst there is an element at point to either remove or ignore.

Comment: Ok, I updated my JS Bin, but I can't seem to get it to work. Can you perhaps take a look and see what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an experiment to tinker with js... you could do this

On the handler where you draw each new div, keep track of the last one drawn

```
var previousCircle,
    yThreshold = 10,
    xThreshold = 10;
document.body.onmousemove = function(e){

    if(mouseDown === "yes"){
        if(elements < 4000){

        var ty = Math.abs(parseInt(previousCircle.style.top, 10) - e.clientY) < yThreshold;
        var tx = Math.abs(parseInt(previousCircle.style.left, 10) - e.clientX) < xThreshold;

         if (ty && tx){
               // if thresholds pass (new is far away enough from old) then draw a new one
               var newCircle = document.createElement("div");
               newCircle.className = "circle";
               newCircle.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px';
               newCircle.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px';
               previousCircle = newCircle;
         }
```

You basically decide to draw a new circle or not, based on the distance to the last circle drawn. You can tweak the "decision" with the threshold vars, the threshold condition `ìf (ty || tx)` or you could even calculate a vector magnitude (radius from center of each circle) to keep things geometrically correct: `radius = sqrt( (newY - oldY)^2 + (newX - oldX)^2 )`.

Granted, this only tracks drawings in sequence, not previous iterations. For that to work you would need to do collision checking on each draw cycle and that means iterating over all drawn divs and comparing their position to the position of the new circle. This is highly inefficient. You could speed up things a bit if you keep track of drawn circles in a index which avoids querying the DOM, only memory.

```
var drawnCircles = [];

for (var i in drawnCircles){
    if (Math.abs(drawnCircles[i].top - e.clientY) < yThreshold && //same for x){
        // draw your new circle
        var newCircle = document.createElement("div");
               newCircle.className = "circle";
               newCircle.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px';
               newCircle.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px';
        // and keep track of it
        drawnCircles.push({top: e.clientY, left: e.clientX});
    }
}
```

Comment: Something so complicated would be inefficient.

Comment: Complicated not always means inefficient, however, what you are trying to do with divs is highly inefficient. There is no magic way around it

Comment: document.elementFromPoint() seems cool tho. I have made a fiddle wit it, but it doesn't seem to like to work. jsbin.com/hocowa/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to do all the logic in JavaScript and track using an array.  Use the DOM only for display purposes and you should see an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure no new element with same position with the elements before, you can create `Array` to hold the drawn positions and draw new element only if the new position is not exist in the array. Example:

```
var mouseDown = "no";
var elements = 0;
var elmList = [];

function setYes() {
    mouseDown = "yes";
}

function setNo() {
    mouseDown = "no";
}

document.body.onmousemove = function (e) {
    if ( mouseDown === "yes" ) {
        if ( elements < 4000 ) {
            var offset = (e.clientY - 25) + 'x' + (e.clientX - 25);

            if ( elmList.indexOf(offset) < 0 ) {
                var newCircle = document.createElement("div");
                newCircle.className = "circle";
                newCircle.style.top = e.clientY - 25 + 'px';
                newCircle.style.left = e.clientX - 25 + 'px';

                elements++;

                elmList.push(offset);

                document.getElementById('appendThingsHere').appendChild(newCircle);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think something like this would be inefficient.

Comment: Looking through a 1-dimensional array with 4000+ items is only going to add to the lag. Maybe with a more appropriate data structure?